# Apache Spark 2.4 is not working with yarn cluster manager?

Tags: hadoop

I have installed Hadoop version 2.8.3 in my windows 10 environment and its working fine. Now when i try to install Apache Spark(version 2.4.0) with yarn as cluster its not working. When i try to submit a spark job using spark-submit for testing , so its coming under ACCEPTED tab in YARN UI after that it fails.

I have attached the image of yarn container logs.[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPxQT.png)